# Redirection with some String React Router

Tags: reactjs, redirect

My question is: I try to use Redirect from react-rooter-dom. I have the redirect function but i want to send a message for the user when i redirect him on the next component.

Here I Redirect with a Pathname:

```
{formSubmit ? <Redirect to={{pathname: "/SignIn"}} /> : <Row></Row>}
```

But how i can redirect with a something like flash message? Thank you.

Comment: You can pass your flash message (data) in `state` using `to` prop of `Redirect` and use this state data in the `SignIn` component to show flash message. See https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect/to-object